# Ruby Inject method problem

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

I have an activerecord array

```
 [#<Lead id: 134, address: "24 elm33",created_at: "2010-11-15 12:08:25", updated_at: "2010-11-16 12:53:36", usd_conv: 2741>, 
#<Lead id: 136, address: "guigiu", created_at: "2010-11-17 16:57:45", updated_at: "2010-11-17 16:57:45", usd_conv: 1000>]
```

and I want to change this using inject to [[created_at, usd_conv (total figure for that time)]]

Any wizards out there know of how to do this?

Comment: Be more specific. You want to get sum, sequence of partial sums?

Comment: sorry, to clarify, I am looking for the squence of partial sums. so from the above example I would have [[2010-11-15 12:08:25, 2741], [2010-11-17 16:57:45, 3741]]. Thanks again guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you need "for each separate `created_at` time, calculate total sum of all `usd_conv` up to this time", this is done by injecting values one-by-one into a data structure.  Here's an example that "injects" records into two-value array:

- the first item accumulates resultant records
- the second accumulates the sum for a current moment

  ```
  array.inject([0,[]]) do |so_far,elem| 
    so_far[0] += elem.usd_conv
    so_far[1] << [elem.created_at, so_far[0]]
    so_far   # Necessary because block should return the next so_far
  end
  ```

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I assume that created_at has so dense resolution, that you'll get hash with number of elements equal number of original records...

Comment: cheers pavel. that is it, apart from the total appearing at the start.  thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
array.collect!{|e| [e.created_at, e.usd_conv]}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer Eimantas :), but Im afraid I am looking for the total of usd_conv. I think inject is the right way to go but I dont know it that well..

Answer (score 0):

It is not typical application of `inject` (`reduce`) method. Idea is to use it while you are reducing array into single value. Using `inject` over other iterators here allows you not to define local variable explicitly (which is good, if you have functional approach). What you really need is combination of `map` and `inject` -- using array of values passed in accumulator is in my opinion dirty trick ;)

As there is no dedicated method to do such things I would stick to `map` (or `map!`):

```
accumulator = 0
ary.map! {|el| [el.created_at, accumulator += el.usd_conv]}
```

Downside is cluttering up higher level scope with accumulator.

Version using `map` seems to be 2--3 times faster when benchmarked (`map` vs `map!` version).